vmwgfx seems to be running on a unsupported hypervisor
So I want to install Ubuntu 24.04 in a virtual machine with VirtualBox 7.0 so I downloaded the iso from Ubuntu's website and put it in virtual machine, but when I boot and select "Install or Try Ubuntu" it shows a very primitive loading screen (instead of the fancy Ubuntu loading screen) with the text "Ubuntu 24.04" and in a couple of seconds it spits out this errors, and I can't install Ubuntu, the only way to have not this happen is to change from VMSVGA TO VBOXSVGA or VBOXVGA but those are crummy and flicker.

I didn't have this happen to me in the past, and also that I used also VirtualBox 7, why is this happening

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Conventional wisdom suggests upgrading after the first point of release, which in this case will be this summer (around August) is the best plan. Don't be too hasty - you might live to regret it if you read some of the questions raised here over the past few days.

You mention virutalbox 7.0; is it updated on your unstated HOST OS? as its likely your virtualbox software is older than your wanted 2024-April release of Ubuntu.  You may need to wait for updates on your HOST OS virtualbox software for this issue to resolve.  FYI:  I can install on my version ; Virtualbox 7.0.16

Just as an aside... the textual plymouth screen (what you pictured) appears when a suitable graphics 'component' was not detected in your hardware in the ~early stages of booting, and does not impact the actual running of the OS itself (once it's booted & running).  It means nothing, and FYI: I saw the error messages you saw (red text) on my virtual 7.0.16 example; but that too didn't impact the operation of the system here  (I only occasionally use virtualbox, so for sure aren't an expert with it; I see it as an easy to use & rather limited hypervisor)

@guiverc I use the latest virtualbox release that is available in the website

I had the same problem, and just ticking 'Enable 3D Acceleration' in VirtualBox solved it.

I had the same issue, to fix I had to change the graphics controller, i read that apparently vmwgfx happens to be the graphic drivers for VMware
In settings > screen > set the 'graphics controller' to VBoxVGA or VBoxSGVA > make sure 'enable 3D acceleration' is unticked.
Should now be able to boot up your system, make sure VirtualBox is up to date

This solution did not work for me.  One thing I did differently to cause this issue (that OP didn't do) was I switched from Wayland to X11, on reboot I started to see this message.

I fixed this by disabling Hyper-V and then uninstalling the Virtualbox guest additions.
sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall
